# Symmetric Exchange Key Sharing

Tags: keys, symmetric, key-exchange

Question:

Suppose that there are 10000 = 10^4 banks and 10 payment card organisations (PCOs).

1. How many secret keys will be needed if each PCO shares a unique secret key with each bank?
2. How many extra secret keys will be needed if every two banks share a unique secret key?

For question 1, I figured that if there are 10,000 banks and 10 PCOs:

```
 10,000 * 10 = 100,000.
```

For question 2, I need to calculate the number of keys if every 2 banks share a key (so I guess for 10,000 banks there would be 5,000 keys?)

```
 5,000 * 10 = 50,000, right?
```

I recall that the solution could be calculated differently, something along the lines of 5,000(5,000-1)*10/2 but I don't understand the logic of this.

Could someone please explain?

(I would appreciate explanation of logic or a direction for research to understand because I feel like this should be quite straightforward and I am unsure).

Thank your for taking the time to read this!

Comment: This is more of a pure math question. Your mistake is that 10,000 banks would not mean 5,000 keys. Let's take 3 banks, A, B, and C. If every 2 banks share a key, then you need a key for (A,B), (A,C), and (B,C). 3 not 3/2. If you play around with small numbers, you should be able to see how you get to the real solution.

Comment: This might also help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum

Comment: Each key between the banks represents a selection of 2 elements from a set. Do you know how to calculate the possible different selections?

Comment: Analogy (pre-covid-19): $n$ persons meet. Each shake hands with all the others. How many handshakes? Hint: each of the $n$ persons does $n-1$ handshakes, and one hanshake serves two persons.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying principle here is that of combinatorics. Think of banks and PCOs as abstract parties. Party $A$ has $|A|$ many members and party $B$ has $|B|$ many respectively. For each $x \in A$ we have $|B|$ secret keys which $x$ shares with members of $B$ meaning we have $|A| \times |B|$ keys.

In your first question, we assumed that for all $x \in A$ and $y \in B$,  we know that $x \neq y$. I. e., The two parties $A$ and $B$ don't share any members! In your second question however, that assumption is not true since $A = B$ which means the party of banks sharing keys with the party of banks, id es, among themselves.

The question here is then how many ways to pick unique $\{x, y\}$ combinations from a set $A$. Well, this is just an $n$ chose $k$: $\binom{n}{k}$ problem. In this case $k = 2, n = |A|$.

> How many secret keys will be needed if each PCO shares a unique secret key with each bank?

$$|A|\times |B| = 10^4 \times 10 = 10^5$$

> How many extra secret keys will be needed if every two banks share a unique secret key?

$$\binom{10^4}{2} = \frac{10^4!}{2!(10^4-2)!} = \frac{10000!}{2(10000-2)!} = \frac{10000!}{2(9998)!} = \frac{9999 \times 10000}{2}$$